# Get the random file name

Tags: jmeter

With a folder contained around 10 files (like 1.csv, 2.csv....10.csv) And I am uploading them to my http request using a beanshell preprocessor using the following script,

```
File folder = new File("C:\\User\\SYSTEMTESTING\\SAMPLENEWFILES\\REUPLOADFILES");
File[] fileForUpload = folder.listFiles();
Random rnd = new Random();
vars.put("CURRENT_FILE", fileForUpload[rnd.nextInt(fileForUpload.length)].getAbsolutePath());
```

want to get the file name which is uploaded using a JSR223 post processer

```
log.info("File Uploaded Is :"+${CURRENT_FILE});
```

I am getting,

```
javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script8.groovy: 1: Missing ')' @ line 1, column 79.
    "File Uploaded Is ------->"+C:\Users\SY
```

In the request body:

```
PUT data:
--RhvwJL7ZdnIMBIaE0CoKVhsE68UNUiH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="CSV_10_MB.csv"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<actual file content, not shown here>
--RhvwJL7ZdnIMBIaE0CoKVhsE68UNUiH--
```

I want the `CSV_10_MB.csv` name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `vars.get`:

```
 log.info("File Uploaded Is :" + vars.get("CURRENT_FILE"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [Groovy's GString](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_gstring_and_string_hashcodes) you need to declare this `CURRENT_FILE` property, if this is what you're looking for you need to amend your code like:

```
def CURRENT_FILE = vars.get("CURRENT_FILE")
log.info("File Uploaded Is: ${CURRENT_FILE}")
```

or use the same [`vars` shorthand](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) for printing the filename to JMeter log like:

```
log.info("File Uploaded Is: " + vars.get("CURRENT_FILE"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dimitri,
`File Uploaded Is ------->C:\\User\\SYSTEMTESTING\\SAMPLENEWFILES\\REUPLOADFILES\CSV_10_MB.csv` but I want to fetch CSV_10_MB.csv, how to use the substring

Comment: `log.info("File Uploaded Is: " + org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.getName(vars.get("CURRENT_FILE")))`